# jMockit: How to expect constructor calls to Mocked objects?

Tags: java, junit, jmockit

I am unit-testing a method performing some serialization operations. I intend to mock the serialization logic. The code is as below:

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));
```

I have created the following mock objects:

```
@Mocked FileInputStream mockFIS;

@Mocked BufferedInputStream mockBIS;

@Mocked ObjectInputStream mockOIS;
```

I have setup a `NonStrictExpectations()` block where I want to expect the above constructor calls.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can specify a complete set of Expectations for a given set of interactions. From [Behavior-based testing with JMockit](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Mocking.html#results):

> A possible test for the doSomething() method could exercise the case
>   where SomeCheckedException gets thrown, after an arbitrary number of
>   successful iterations. Assuming that we want (for whatever reasons) to
>   record a complete set of expectations for the interaction between
>   these two classes, we might write the test below:

```
@Test
public void doSomethingHandlesSomeCheckedException() throws Exception
{
  new Expectations() {
     DependencyAbc abc;

     {
        new DependencyAbc(); // expect constructor

        abc.intReturningMethod(); result = 3;

        abc.stringReturningMethod();
        returns("str1", "str2");
        result = new SomeCheckedException();
     }
  };

  new UnitUnderTest().doSomething();
}
```

Comment: After "abc" is constructed, can you test that it is passed into some other method?  def.someMethod(abc)?  I am having problems with this because the references are not equal.